# UIWebView scrolling issues

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, scroll

I am using a UIWebView which is updated often using

```
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

The html string loaded changes to highlight the next word the user has to type in. To scroll the text as the user types, I use:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
         [NSString stringWithFormat: @"window.scrollBy(0, %d);", yScroll]];
```

,which is called within

```
-(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

inside the web view delegate.

Although this works, the web view is scrolled to the top each and every time it is loaded, and later scrolled to the right position, which causes an undesirable flicker.

Interestingly enough this flicker appears on the device but not on the simulator.

I have tried setting the offset alternatively like:

```
webView.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, yScroll);
```

which scrolls the web view but has no effect on the flicker.

I have also overriden

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

and set the hidden property of the web view to YES, made the scroll, and revealed the web view within the

```
-(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

method but to no real effect.

My last resort would be trimming lines from the html string as the user types, loading the updated string every time and avoiding the scroll altogether.

Before I follow that path, does anyone have an idea on how to get the scrolling to work without the "flicker"?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you add the JavaScript to the string in `loadHTMLString` instead?  If not, then you could do a clunky double-buffer, and have two webViews.  Hide the old one and show the new one after executing `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:`

Comment: Adding javascript to the `loadHTMLString` sounds like a decent idea. I thought about making a double-buffer with 2 webviews too but I'd rather steer away from that. I'll try adding js to `loadHTMLString` and let you know. Thanks

Comment: I have managed to load the html text and scroll within the webview by calling `javascript:scrollTo(x,y)` on the onload event of the html page, thus avoiding to load the top of the page first and then scroll to the desired point. This worked smoother than before but not good enough to keep as a solution. I ended up subtracting a line from the text every time the user finishes typing a line. Anyhow, thanks for your suggestion ikuragames